# Instantiate several children with similar arguments

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have the class `Base`, and the classes `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, ... that extend this class. `Base` has a constructor with too many parameters (bad practice, but I can't change that). Most of the children classes have only these parameters, but some children classes can have 1 or 2 more arguments. Something like this:

```
class Base {
   private readonly string _arg1;
   private readonly string _arg2;
   (...)

   public Base(string arg1, string arg2, string arg3, ..., string arg_n) {
       _arg1 = arg1
       _arg2 = arg2
      (...)
   }
}

class A : Base {
   public A(string arg1, string arg2, string arg3, ..., string arg_n) : 
       base(arg1, arg2, arg3, ..., arg_n)
   }
}

class B : Base {
   private readonly string _arg_m;

   public B(string arg1, string arg2, string arg3, ..., string arg_n, string arg_m) : 
       base(arg1, arg2, arg3, ..., arg_n)
       _arg_m = arg_m;
   }
}
etc...
```

I want to instantiate one element of each class, using the same instances for the arguments. Something like:

```
var arg1 = "something";
(...)
var arg_n = "something";

var a = new A(arg1, arg2, arg3, ... , arg_n);
var b = new B(arg1, arg2, arg3, ... , arg_n, "foo");
(...)
```

I would like to do it without repeating the code too much. I though I could create a factory:

```
class Factory {
    Factory(string arg1, string arg2, string arg3, ..., string arg_n) {
       (...)
    }
```

and then reuse these parameters. My original code would be simplified to

```
var arg1 = "something";
(...)
var arg_n = "something";
var factory = new Factory(arg1, arg2, arg3, ... , arg_n);

var a = factory.GetA();
var b = factory.GetB("foo");
(...)
```

but then the factory would contain all the `new A(list of arguemnts)` for all the children. So, basically, I'm not reducing code but moving it.

Is there a pattern to create all these children without so much verbosity? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a class that holds all your arguments:

```
class BaseArgs
{
   public string Arg1 {get;}
   public string Arg2 {get;}

   public BaseArgs(string arg1, arg2)
   {
     Arg1 = arg1;
     Arg2 = arg2;
   }
}
```

Pass this object to your derived classes:

```
class A : Base
{
  public A(BaseArgs args) : base(args.Arg1, args.Arg2)
  {
  }
}

class B : Base
{
   private string additional;

  public B(BaseArgs args, string additional) : base(args.Arg1, args.Arg2)
  {
    this.additional = additional;
  }
}
```

You can create your `BaseArgs` object once and pass it to all the instances of your derived classes:

```
var baseArgs = new BaseArgs("arg1","arg2");
var a = new A(baseArgs);
var b = new B(baseArgs, "foo");
```

If you add setters to the properties of the `BaseArgs`, you can even modify only a few of the parameters between creating the instances:

```
var baseArgs = new BaseArgs("arg1","arg2");
var a = new A(baseArgs);
baseArgs.Arg1 = "changed";
var b = new B(baseArgs, "foo");
```

Answer (score 0):

## The builder pattern

The builder allows you to collect the parameters before building the object. Here is an example of how a builder would work:

```
class Base
{
    public Base(int a, int b, int c)
    {
    }
}


class FirstImplementation : Base
{
    public FirstImplementation(int a, int b, int c) : base(a, b, c)
    {
    }
}

class Builder
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

    public Builder SetA(int a)
    {
        this.a = a;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder SetB(int b)
    {
        this.b = b;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder SetC(int c)
    {
        this.c = c;
        return this;
    }

    public FirstImplementation Build()
    {
        // Add your null checks here!
        return new FirstImplementation(a, b, c);
    }
}
```

## Director

As you can see, with the builder, you still need to supply all the parameters each time. This is where the director comes in. The director is optional, but makes your problem disappear.

```
class Director
{
    public Base BuildMinimalViableProduct()
    {
        return new Builder()
            .SetA(1)
            .Build();
    }

    public Base BuildFullFeaturedProduct()
    {
        return new Builder()
            .SetA(1)
            .SetB(2)
            .SetC(3)
            .Build();
    }
}
```

## More info

This page explains the idea behind the builder:

- https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/builder/csharp/example#lang-features
- https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/builder

Answer (score 0):

One alternative would be to use [Dependency Injection Container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection). This lets you register all the dependencies in the container, and let the container figure out how to construct each object. Typical usage may look something like

```
    var collection = new ServiceCollection()
    collection.AddSingleton(myDependency1);
    collection.AddSingleton(myDependency2);
    collection.AddTransient<A>();
    collection.AddSingleton<B>();
...
    provider = collection.BuildServiceProvider();
    var a= provider.GetService<A>();
    var b= provider.GetService<B>();
```

This tend to work best if the parameters have different types. If all parameters are strings there is no way for the container to figure out what parameter goes where. But if all your parameters are strings you probably have other problems as well.

If parameters are related some way it can be useful to gather them into a parameter object that can be registered in the container and used as a dependency. But I would caution against throwing arbitrary unrelated parameters into such a parameter class, since this can cause more problems than it solves.

Also note that using a dependency injection container works best when implemented at the start of a project and used to construct most types. It can be difficult to re architecture an existing application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a builder that only instantiates types inherited from `Base` dynamically using the variable array keyword `params` for your arguments. This solution should allow you to build any type as long as the inheriting types all pass the arguments required by `Base` correctly.

```
public class BaseBuilder
{
    public static T Build<T>(params string[] args) where T : Base
    {
      var ctor = typeof(T).GetConstructors().First();
      var parameters = ctor.GetParameters();
      var arguments = new List<string>();
    
      //Check args here
      if (args == null || args.Length < parameters.Length)
        throw new ArgumentException($"Invalid number of arguments, was expecting {parameters.Length}");

      for (var i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++)
      {
        arguments.Add(args[i]);
      }
      return (T)ctor.Invoke(arguments.ToArray());
}
```

}

Then you can have a collection of arguments in a single array and as long as the ordering is consistent only the arguments that are actually required will be used.

```
var args = new[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };
var a = BaseBuilder.Build<A>(args);
var b = BaseBuilder.Build<B>(args);
```